# iPhone : Problem while displaying captured image in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiwebview

I am displaying graph by capturing image and loading into a webView using `loadHTMLString` method.

The images come fine when displayed the first time. But it does not seem to change when I recapture the image which is different.

Also I have checked that the image name is same and the new image is recaptured every time.

It seems to be some issue with UIWebView reloading.

what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same image with the same name is being captured, it may be cached in the UIWebView, causing it to display as the initial image instead of the updated images. If there's a way to use the reload function of the webview (which, in a browser will often check for updates to images), this might help.

If that doesn't solve it, I'd make sure that you're not somehow saving and appending the captured HTML to a variable, causing the new text to be appended to the end of the variable and not loaded.